# Android Kotlin - retrofit2 get JSONArray instead Model List

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("testgetmemes/")
    fun getMemes(): Call<List<Memes>>

}

object ApiClient {

    var BASE_URL:String="https://www.blaaa.com/"
    val getClient: ApiInterface
        get() {

            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create()

            val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)

        }
}
```

and inside a function :

```
    val call: Call<List<Memes>> = ApiClient.getClient.getMemes()
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Memes>> {

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<Memes>>?, response: Response<List<Memes>>) {
            Log.d(tagg, response!!.body()!!.toString())
            //setMemes(response!!.body()!!, gal)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Memes>>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.d(tagg, t!!.toString())
        }

    })
```

I want to get the JSONArray instead of this ready to use Model List! Otherwise I would have to do a lot of changes and workarounds because I usually use beautiful loopj, this retrofit2 thing is only to make APIs work on older Android versions.

I tried that by replacing all `<List<Memes>>` with `<JSONArray>` but then I get this response:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $
```

How to do this??

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it now, using Gson:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
```

..

```
JSONArray(Gson().toJson(response.body()))
```

No need to replace `<List<Memes>>` with `<JSONArray>`